# play icon is not changing to pause icon using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I had earlier defined an audioElement that stores an audio file. When click the play icon only audio gets played and icon doesn't change.

After the javascript I have provided the relevant HTML code

```
const AudioElement = new Audio("audios/1.mp3");
const masterplay = document.getElementById("masterplay");
let playIcon = document.getElementById("playid");

masterplay.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (AudioElement.paused || AudioElement.currentTime === 0) {
    AudioElement.play();
    playIcon.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
    playIcon.classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
  } else {
    AudioElement.pause();
    playIcon.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
    playIcon.classList.add('fa-circle-play');
  }
})
```

```
<div class="bottom">
  <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="myprogressbar">
  <div class="icons">
    <!-- font awesome icons -->
    <i class="fa-solid fa-backward play"></i>
    <span id="masterplay">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play" id="playid"></i>
    </span>
    <i class="fa-solid fa-forward play"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4760bd9cb1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check if your js is running before the element exists (most likely).   `let playIcon = document.getElementById("playid"); if (playIccon == null) alert("too soon");`

Comment: You have *two* play icons - are you changing the correct one?   Do you have css that hides the one in `#masterplay`?

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome uses `<svg>` to display the icon. You should search `masterplay` for that `svg`:

```js
let playIcon= masterplay.querySelector("svg");
```

---

```js
const AudioElement = new Audio("https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/1-MB-MP3.mp3");
const masterplay = document.getElementById("masterplay");

masterplay.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

   let playIcon= masterplay.querySelector("svg");
    
   if (AudioElement.paused || AudioElement.currentTime === 0) {
       AudioElement.play();
       playIcon.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
       playIcon.classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
   } else {
       AudioElement.pause();
       playIcon.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
       playIcon.classList.add('fa-circle-play');
    }
})
```

```html
<div class="bottom">
    <input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="myprogressbar">
    <div class="icons">
        <!-- font awesome icons -->
        <i class="fa-solid fa-backward"></i>
        <span  id="masterplay">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play" id="playid"></i>
        </span> 
        <i class="fa-solid fa-forward"></i>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4760bd9cb1.js" crossorigin="anonymous"> </script>
```