# font awesome play icon is not changing to pause icon when in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

the font awesome icon is not changing from play to pause when i click on it i have tried a bunch of methods but this one seems to be more accurate but icon still doesnt change.please tell whats wrong with this one or provide some other method.

```
const makeallplay= ()=>{
  let smallplayicons= songplayicon.querySelectorAll("svg");
  Array.from(smallplayicons).forEach((element) => {
    element.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
    element.classList.add('fa-circle-play');
  })
}

Array.from(songplayicon.querySelectorAll('svg')).forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    makeallplay();
    e.target.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
    e.target.classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
  });
});
```

**here is the relevant HTML code**

```
<div class="song-item">
  <img  src="logos/song1.jpg" alt="1">
  <span>ILLAHI</span>
  <span class="song-info">3:24 <span class="songplayicon"> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play play "></i></span> </span>
</div>
<div class="song-item">
  <img  src="logos/cover2.jpeg" alt="1">
  <span>The Nights</span>
  <span class="song-info">3:26 <span class="songplayicon"> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play play "></i></span> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please finish of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77346282/play-icon-is-not-changing-to-pause-icon-using-javascript) before asking the same again...

Answer (score 0):

Many issues.

- Missing `{`
- Where do you define `songplayicon`
- There are no SVG tags in your example

There is not much correct in your script so I did not try to "fix" it but rewrote it from scratch

Here is a delegation version. I wrapped your items in a div

I changed to code to toggle the other icons when necessary.

```js
const container = document.getElementById('song-items')
const icons = container.querySelectorAll('.songplayicon i');
container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest('span.songplayicon');
  if (!tgt) return;
  const thisIcon = tgt.querySelector('i');
  const targetPlay = thisIcon.matches('.fa-circle-play'); // we want to play
  icons.forEach(icon => {
    if (targetPlay) {
      icon.classList.toggle('fa-circle-play', targetPlay);
      icon.classList.toggle('fa-circle-pause', !targetPlay);
    }
  });
  thisIcon.classList.toggle('fa-circle-pause', targetPlay);
  thisIcon.classList.toggle('fa-circle-play', !targetPlay);
  // here you can use code to play or pause
  // const audio = tgt.closest('div.song-item').querySelector('audio');
  // audio[targetPlay ? 'play' : 'pause'];
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css" />

<div id="song-items">
  <div class="song-item">
    <img src="logos/song1.jpg" alt="1">
    <span>ILLAHI</span>
    <span class="song-info">3:24 <span class="songplayicon"> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play play "></i></span> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="song-item">
    <img src="logos/cover2.jpeg" alt="1">
    <span>The Nights</span>
    <span class="song-info">3:26 <span class="songplayicon"> <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-play play "></i></span> </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok i understand this but what is wrong with my code well aside from missing } ?

Comment: See update. There is not much correct in your script so I did not try to "fix" it but rewrote it from scratch

Comment: alright and what changes i should make in this code so that when i click on second icon to play the first one automatically becomes pause. Because right now i have to click icons indvidually to change them

Comment: See updated code

Answer (score 0):

The code you've provided is almost correct, but there is a small issue with your event listener function's structure. You need to use curly braces to group statements inside the event listener. Here's the corrected code:

```
const makeAllPlay = () => {
    const smallPlayIcons = document.querySelectorAll(".songplayicon svg");
    smallPlayIcons.forEach((element) => {
        element.classList.remove('fa-circle-pause');
        element.classList.add('fa-circle-play');
    });
};

document.querySelectorAll('.songplayicon svg').forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        makeAllPlay();
        e.target.classList.remove('fa-circle-play');
        e.target.classList.add('fa-circle-pause');
    });
});
```

Here are the changes made:

1. The event listener function now correctly groups statements within curly braces.
2. I also fixed the selector to match the "svg" elements within the
   **.songplayicon** elements.

With these changes, when you click on a play icon, it should toggle between the play and pause icons as expected.